Catch block not getting executed in java ExecutorService threads
We want to execute a task asynchronously through a fixed thread pool. If there are any exceptions in the task we want to update the status in the database as FAILED. We have observed that the catch block sometimes never gets executed, hence the status always remains PENDING.
ExecutorService pdfGenerationThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pdfGenerationThreadPoolSize,
                new NamedThreadFactory("pdfGenerationThreadPool"));
//..
pdfGenerationThreadPool.submit(() -> {
            try {
                generateDocumentFromTemplate(template);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //update status in database as failed.
            }
      }

I tried to reproduce the issue through Spring Boot test cases. The issue does reproduce when the test cases are executed multiple times. Out of 20 times, it doesn't execute the catch block 15 times.
What could be wrong in the above code that could be causing the issue? And what are the best practices of making sure that catch blocks in runnable threads do get executed always?

Does NamedThreadFactory create daemon threads or non-daemon threads? If it creates daemon threads, your application will exit even if those daemon are still doing work. That is the only explanation I can think of why the catch wouldn't be reached; in all other situations (unless an Error or other Throwable than Exception is thrown).

In any case, you really need to provide a [mre].

submit() returns a Future, if you call its get() you will: know the task was completed, and get an ExecutionException if an Exception was not caught by the catch block

@MarkRotteveel - how do I know if the thread factory is creating daemon threads or non-daemon?
@user85421 - I cannot call future.get() since this needs to be an async operation. This is executed via a rest api call. There is a separate rest api to fetch the status of the operation.

I don't know what that NamedThreadFactory is, so you'd need to provide the source or if it is in a library, its fully qualified name, or consult is documentation to see what kinds of threads it creates.

In a first step, I would change the code like this:
final ExecutorService pdfGenerationThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( pdfGenerationThreadPoolSize, new NamedThreadFactory( "pdfGenerationThreadPool" ) );
//…
pdfGenerationThreadPool.submit( () -> 
{
  try 
  {
    generateDocumentFromTemplate( template );
  }
  catch( final Throwable t ) 
  {
    // update status in database as failed.
  }
}

Error is not a child class of Exception, so it would not have been caught by your original code.
Of course I do not know whether generateDocumentFromTemplate() would throw an Error, but on the other side, this is at this point the only idea I have why the thread terminates without executing the catch block (other than performing the task as desired – meaning without an error condition and not throwing any kind of exception at all).

I agree with having the Throwable block but like I said - this isn't the cause. The catch block does get executed few times when the test case is executed multiple times.

@AndyDufresne – Ok, then you need to provide more details about the test case! Is it guaranteed that each test case refers its own entity on the database? Synchronisation is either not required or properly implemented? In the test cases, too?
